# materialize tab active not working in tabs

Tags: css, tabs, materialize

I am trying to get class active to the photography tab but **class="active"** is not working. I have perfectly initialized the tabs in scripts.

```
<div class="col s12 l6 offset-l2">
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li class="tab col s6 pink-text text-darken-3" >
            <a href="#Photography" class="active pink-text text-darken-3" >Photography</a>
          </li>
          <li class="tab col s6 pink-text text-darken-3">
            <a href="#Editing " class="pink-text text-darken-3"  >Editing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="Photography" class="col s12 ">
          <p class="purple-text text-darken-2">Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
          <p class="purple-text text-darken-2">Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </div>
        <div id="Editing" class="col s12">
          <p class="purple-text text-darken-2">Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
          <p class="purple-text text-darken-2">Lorem ipsum dolor </p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: First check if you are getting any error in console.

Comment: It ran after I change Photography and Editing to the smallcase like photography and editing. I don't know why it happened but if I use Capital letter then it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It ran after I change Photography and Editing to the smallcase like photography and editing. I don't know why it happened but if I use Capital letter then it doesn't works and work when it is in smallcase.